# why onsubmit event handler is not working in php interpreter

Tags: javascript, php

I am reading through Learning PHP, MySQL & Javascript 4th edition and in chapter 16 I encountered a problem.

Onsubmit event handler is not working in `<?php ... ?>` (PHP interpreter), while it is working just fine without it.
am I missing something?

I removed some parts of the code to just show the problem

```
<?php
echo <<<_END
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>An Example Form</title>
                <style>
                    .signup {
                        border:1px solid #999999;
                        font:  normal 14px helvetica;
                        color: #444444;
                    }    
                </style>
                <script>
                    function validate(form) {
                        fail  = validateForename(form.forename.value)

                        if(fail == "")   return true
                        else { alert(fail); return false }
                    }

                    function validateForename(field) {
                        return (field == "") ? "No Forename was entered.\n" : ""
                    }
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
                    <th colspan="2" align="center">Signup Form</th>
                    <form method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
                        <tr><td>Forename</td>
                            <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="forename"></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2" align="center">
                            <input type="submit" value="Signup"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </form>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
_END;
?>
```

with this code in use, javascript alert function is not showing any alert even if I submit an empty form.

Here is just the HTML/CSS/JS:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>An Example Form</title>
  <style>
    .signup {
      border: 1px solid #999999;
      font: normal 14px helvetica;
      color: #444444;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function validate(form) {
      fail = validateForename(form.forename.value)

      if (fail == "") return true
      else {
        alert(fail);
        return false
      }
    }

    function validateForename(field) {
      return (field == "") ? "No Forename was entered.\n" : ""
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <table border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="5" bgcolor="#eeeeee">
    <th colspan="2" align="center">Signup Form</th>
    <form method="post" onsubmit="return validate(this)">
      <tr>
        <td>Forename</td>
        <td><input type="text" maxlength="32" name="forename"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2" align="center">
          <input type="submit" value="Signup"></td>
      </tr>
    </form>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML/CSS/JS work fine. This is likely caused by the `<<<HEREDOC`

Comment: If you give me permission to modify your question to show you that it works fine, I will do that for you.

Comment: how I can give you permission to modify it?

Comment: Just in a comment - sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: yes, as I mentioned it just works fine without <?php ... ?>

Comment: @HappyAnt was right it seems the writer forgot to use \\n instead of \n or things have changed since 2014. thank you, guys.

Comment: So you are saying that if you click the "Run code snippet" I placed into your question, and the submit the blank form, that you DO NOT see the alert?

Comment: No I mean it works fine that way, but I just wanted to don't remove HEREDOC. sorry if the question was unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to escape the newline `\n` twice or your HTML output will not look like intended:

```
return (field == "") ? "No Forename was entered.\\n" : ""
```

Comment: How does this answer this question: _javascript alert function is not showing any alert._ ?

Comment: I mean the problem is when I submit empty form, javascript doesn't give any alert while it has to do it

Comment: It's because of the single backslash, which must be escaped twice so the javascript code is generated correctly. Without double backslash the `\n` willl mess up your javascript.

Comment: @Randy Casburn: I don't know what your problem is. I tested the original code and it didn't work, then I tested the code I provided and it worked.

Comment: @HappyAnt - click the run button in the OP's question. It works.

Comment: I did never say that the pure HTML won't work. What PHP echoed did not work.

Comment: Now I get it @HappyAnt +1